# Why do I have 2 cursors? OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, display, cursor

I have a MacBook Air 11 inch, connected to a Xerox monitor. For some reason I have 2 cursors, one lagging slightly behind the other. I tried unplugging the Xerox monitor, and that worked but when I tried it again, I still had 2 cursors

Comment: What won't work again? The connection to the Xerox monitor, or the double cursors? What video connection are you using?

Comment: @IconDaemon Sry for the bad wording, what I mead it that after unplugging it the second time I plugged it in again, and I still had 2 cursors. The Xerox has a VGA cord, which I connect to my macbook air with a VGA to mini-display

Comment: The problem still persists, anyone think they know a way to fix it?

Comment: Do you have another VGA <> MDP adaptor and VGA cable to test with? What resolution are you setting the Mac to? What resolution settings are available on the Xerox?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what made it work correctly again (I only have 1 cursor). I think its because it was all disconnected and shut off. Not exactly sure though